# How can I remove this URL from Google?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index

Do you know how I deindex this page?

"https://www.example.com/click/B00354KQHA/US/mybestroadbikes-20/" There are several links similar to this one that appear on the Google results.

I am using Yoast SEO. I do not know if I can use it to solve this issue.

Comment: Are these URLs on your site? If not, have you tried them using curl or wget (not a browser)? If you use Google Search Console, are these showing up as 404 errors?

Comment: I removed the link to your site to prevent it from being closed. As it is, your question is not entirely clear. For example, the questions I posted earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that you have affiliate links which have 302 redirected to the Amazon or another affiliate site. This is a common issue for affiliate websites.

The issue with 302 redirects is that Google index these redirect pages and even are using Page Title and Meta Description from a destination page. See the screenshot:
[image: Snapshot of the SERPS]

Here are two solutions:

1. Set all your affiliate links with `rel="nofollow"`. Example:

   `<a href="https://www.example.com/click/B00354KQHA/US/mybestroadbikes-20/" rel="nofollow">ISM Adamo Road Saddle</a>`
2. Update your `robots.txt` file, if you are sure, that all your affiliate links start with `/click/`:

   ```
   User-agent: *
   Disallow: /click/
   ```

Probably, I would recommend doing both these things.

Next step, when you made recommended changes above, you can start to remove the links using Google Search Console Remove URLs tool or just wait till Google will slowly remove these URLs, but it could take months.

Comment: Thanks! I think that the rel="nofollow" was already included in the correct way. I will disallow them and remove the URLs.